# Use a javascript variable in the PHP Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags

I want to use the value of 'n1' variable in the 5 and 6 lines off code. This means that the 'n1' variable is a JavaScript variable and I want to use it in the following PHP code lines:

```
var x=50*Math.cos((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[n1][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+100;
var y=50*Math.sin((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[n1][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+75;

<script>
for (var n1 = 0; n1 <= 3; n1++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100,75);
    var x=50*Math.cos((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[n1][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+100;
    var y=50*Math.sin((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[n1][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+75;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    x=Quarterx(x,y,<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>);
    y=Quartery(x,y,<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>);
    ctx.font = "10px Arial";
    ctx.strokeText('<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][0]); ?>',x,y);  
}
</script>
```

How can i do that? thanks.

Comment: To implement something like this, you need to use Ajax.

Comment: This question has been answered literally HUNDREDS of times before. SEARCH first, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont use javascript variable in php, but you can  create a loop in php

```
<script>
<?php for ($n1=0;$n1<=3;$n1++){ ?>
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(100,75);
   var x=50*Math.cos((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[$n1][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+100;
   var y=50*Math.sin((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[$n1][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+75;
   ctx.lineTo(x,y);
   x=Quarterx(x,y,<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>);
   y=Quartery(x,y,<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>);
   ctx.font = "10px Arial";
   ctx.strokeText('<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][0]); ?>',x,y);  
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

it works?